# changing the default URL i.e. http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/ in Webservices using axis

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I tried an web service example from the below mention link

http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/02/web-services-example-using-axis-2-and.html

In the example when we generate the client code using wsdl2java the url used is as mention in title i.e.  http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/ Is there any way by which i can use custom name insted of axis2/services for ex. ponds/accounts

I tried with packages, keeping the aar file in newly created folder in services directory but not working

Comment: does this help ?
http://kushanxp.blogspot.com/2010/12/embedding-axis2-into-existing.html

Comment: Just to be sure:
QUOTE:
Axis2 assumes that all your service implementations are in a directory called services, in WEB-INF folder. so if you are not changing that, you don't have to modify axis2.xml file.
( From the link i posted )

Answer (score 0):

Try this

in the axis2.xml you'll see

```
<parameter name="contextRoot">axis2</parameter>
```

Its usually commented out and I suspect axis just uses axis2 by default. but try changing it and see if that fixes it

I don't think you're using eclipse but if you are it has an easier way of changing the context root through Project Properties -> Web Project Settings